# How to search and sort multiple columns into one column

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bkyH0_a6Wsk4iYLhJfdlBndhD8hvXFmiVCO8cVcCOKM/edit?usp=drivesdkhttps) is like my input. if theres better way to import that site, you can suggest me it

I need to find all columns with prices and put them in one big column-table. My point is to use vlookup afterwards.
Also I need formula not normal references, because the table can vary. Similar thing is that there are always names+price(+$}.

It should maybe check every cell with text and check if theres number next to it, then add it to big table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 Original!D:E; Original!H:I; Original!L:M; Original!P:Q}; 
 "where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null"; 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @aa fixed, try now

Comment: @player0, the ARRAYFORMULA part of the expression doesn't seem to be required, is it?

Comment: @kirkg13 yes, residue from the previous attempt. fixed